# Golang default return 2 decimal places

Tags: go

I need to export the json with default 2 decimal places for amount.

In Query i have used "SELECT FORMAT(amount, 2) from product"

```
type product struct {
    Amount float32 `db:"Amount"`
}
```

So i need if the Amount value is 99 it should export 99.00
every time it is returning 99.

I just simply retrieving data from DB and exporting like json marshal the dynamic product struct.
From DB i am getting with decimal formatted value but the decimal getting lost when we are assigning the value in struct.

NOTE :: fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", value) will not work.

Comment: Both `99` and `99.00` carry the same knowledge. Your problem is with _formatting_ your data, not data itself.

Comment: @zerkms , yes from DB i am getting 99.00 and i need to keep the value with same format.

Comment: "from DB i am getting 99.00" --- if you retrieve a string - you should treat it as a string then.

Comment: As stated, `99` and `99.00` are identical `float32` values. All we see here is a data structure. If you're concerned about the formatting of values when they are displayed, please show the code you are using to display said values.

Comment: The data i am exporting on API call, not displaying in GO Application, the client site expect the values with default 2 decimal places.
The values are identical but is there anyway to export the values with 2 decimal.

Comment: How do you "export" it?

Comment: If the client side expects this, it needs to be fixed.

Comment: update your question with your attempted code as well and add your research efforts.

Answer (score 1):

To export 99.00 instead of 99 ,you can convert the amount value from int to float with specified number of decimal points.Here is a simple code with the same logic :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    amount := 99

    var desiredVal float64 = float64(amount)

    fmt.Printf("amount = %d \n", amount)

    fmt.Printf("\nnew amount= %.2f", desiredVal)

}
```

Output:

```
amount = 99 

new amount= 99.00
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but printf or sprintf will not work in my case. i am exporting the structure as json.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the formatting needs to be done on the client side - it make sense that way.

Nevertheless here is a workaround - just create a another type with the formatted values, and marshal it:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type product struct {
    Amount float32
}

func main() {
    p := product{Amount: 99.00}

    fmt.Println(string(marshal(p)))
}

type N struct {
    Amount string
}

func NewN(p product) N {
    return N{
        Amount: fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", p.Amount),
    }
}

func marshal(p product) []byte {
    n := NewN(p)
    r, _ := json.Marshal(&n)

    return r
}
```

```
{"Amount":"99.00"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
For now i have change the datatype of amount to string and exporting as a string, i was looking for without change the datatype is there anyway we can export.
e.g. {"Amount": 99.00}

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to assign some improbable value like 7777.777 and then marshal the structure. Then do a string replace of the marshalled string i.e., replace  7777.77 with 99.00.